# Why are inflatable pillows not allowed on board?

Tags: safety, airlines, cabin

Inflatable cushions designed to ensure extra space that children sleep comfortably between the passenger seats are not accepted aboard by most of the airline companies for they can obstruct evacuation in case of emergency situation. In my opinion, there is no safety risk for these accessories in case they are permitted to be used on a level flight(cruise phase). Is there any additional reason why airline companies do not accept similar products on board? What else can be the reason not accepting inflatable cushion like accessories on a flight. Does it really pose a safety risk and compromise flight safety in a level flight?

Comment: You answered your own question. What exactly are you looking for here?

Comment: Isn’t it unreasonable not to accept these accessories because there is no emergency evacuation in a level flight(I don’t mean that these accessories are to be allowed to use during taxi, take-off and landing phases). In addition, i try to understand the logic that some airlines are accepting and some others are not. What is the logic behind this?

Comment: I don't see what you want here. This isn't a discussion board, and even if it was, our opinions won't change airline regulations. I'm voting to close this as it seems to fall under _"your question is just a rant in disguise: “______ sucks, am I right?”_ - see [help/dont-ask]

Comment: @GolfCharlie Unfortunately, this is a legitimate question.  The answer may be linked to the effects of decompression.  Even under normal flight conditions, it is common to have cabin pressure lower than 14.7 psi.  In the event of a hull failure at altitude, "inflatable" objects would likely explode.  There for, restricting them is reasonable.

Comment: @GolfCharlie your assumption that there is no safety risk is completely incorrect. Three words make that so: Clear Air Turbulence. And that is just one example. If people are so worried about their children sleeping comfortably on a short flight, there are other options for travel, including private vehicles, buses and trains.

Answer (score 6):

***"they can obstruct evacuation in case of emergency situation."***
Thats the reason.

***"In my opinion, there is no safety risk"***
Please describe your qualifications and level of expertise to have a valid opinion.

***"Does it really pose a safety risk and compromise flight safety in a level flight?"***
If an emergency occurs at cruising altitude, and the plane begins an emergency descent, emergency landing and emergency evacuation while the plane is on fire, is your first thought really going to be *"I better be sure to deflate my kid's inflatable cushion"*?

I think you are more likely be pre-occupied with oxygen masks, seat-belts, smoke inhalation, holding your child, and running for the emergency exits.  You will forget all about the inflatable cushion.  It might well trap and kill people behind you during the emergency evacuation.

Comment: In order not to obstruct evacuation and affect other passengers comfort/safety, why it’s not allowed to be used only in mid seats(on wide-body aircrafts only) and in window seats (both narrow/wide body aircrafts)? Should it be understood that airliners that allow inflatable pillows are less safe?

Comment: They’ll be too busy grabbing their luggage, if recent incidents are any indication.